# Prefix field name serializing with Jackson

Tags: json, spring, jackson

What is the easiest way to add `@` prefix to `@XmlAtrribute`-annotated field names with Jackson serialization to JSON? Right now both `@XmlElement` and `@XmlAttribute` are converted in the same way. My goal is to distinguish attributes from elements in JSON.

Spring beans config:

```
<bean id="jackson2HttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"
          autowire-candidate="false">
        <property name="objectMapper" ref="messageObjectMapper"/>
    </bean>
```

The ObjectMapper config:

```
public class MessageObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper implements InitializingBean {

    private boolean indentOutput = false;
    public void setIndentOutput(boolean indentOutput) {
        this.indentOutput = indentOutput;
    }

    public MessageObjectMapper() {
        super();

        this.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        this.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        this.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        this.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    }


    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        this.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, this.indentOutput);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Jackson MixIns worked for me.

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations

I've used Jackson 2.7.4 and syntax from this tutorial:
http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/024-modifying-fields-external-domain-jackson-mixin/